# How to use geolocation in Angular JS Google Maps?

Tags: angularjs

I use [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/) in project. I have not found information in tutoria; how to use geolocation and detect current user position. How I can do it?

I tried:

```
$scope.getGeoLocation = function (){
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($scope.showPosition);
                } else {
                    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
                }
            }

            $scope.showPosition = function (position) {
                $scope.map.bounds = {
                    northeast : position.coords.latitude,
                    southwest: position.coords.longitude
                }

                $scope.map.center = {latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude}
                console.log(position.coords.longitude);
            }
```

But I get error:

> Invalid map bounds for new value:
>   {"northeast":40.409261699999995,"southwest":49.8670924}

Comment: Refer : GitHub - ngGeolocation : https://github.com/ninjatronic/ngGeolocation

Comment: I believe it's because you are trying to reassign bounds value which is not in current area.

Answer (score 0):

Check conditions in source:
`if !newValue?.northeast?.latitude? 
   or !newValue?.northeast?.longitude? 
   or !newValue?.southwest?.latitude?
   or !newValue?.southwest?.longitude?
        $log.error "Invalid map bounds for new value: #{JSON.stringify newValue}"`